# How to add a button on the WKWebView Top bar or NavigationalBar

Tags: swift3, uiview, wkwebview

I want to add button on the Navigationbar of the WKWebView when it plays youTube Video.

When the WKWebView successfully loaded a youtube video, it show a red button for user to click to view.

when this red button is clicked, it will expand and cover the entire screen.
at the Top Bar or Navigational bar of the screen, there are some buttons: a) X btn to close, b) Expand vertical btn 3) a sound btn.

```
The Problem:
I want to a button on this bar which contain the above 3 buttons.


I did the following but it didnot work.

I embed a WKWebView in the UiViewController and I add the following code in viewDidLoad:

 let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

 let leftBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBtn
```

Please help.

Thanks